# Multiple values in list

Tags: list, conditional

I am using SharePoint from Office365.
Two lists are given:

```
List 1:
1 | Person1
2 | Person2
3 | Person3
...



List 2:
1 | Activity1 | Person1;Person3
2 | Activity2 | Person2
3 | Activity3 | Person1;Person2;Person3
4 | Activity4 | Person2;Person3
```

I want to add another column to list 1 that lists all activites where the person from the person column is included in the third column of list 2. So:

```
1 | Person1 | Activity1;Activity3
2 | Person2 | Activity2;Activity3;Activity4
3 | Person3 | Activity1;Activity3;Activity4
```

Thanks for helping.

Lexinas

Comment: Have you experimented with using Look-up columns?  A Look-up column in List A should be able to do this for you.  If your lists are in different site collections then you'd need to use some 3rd party solution like Sparqube columns

Comment: You can use list web parts and connected web parts to achieve this. Link the column 1 from list A to the column 3 from list B.